# For $A$ a unital Banach Algebra and $B$ maximal ableian subalgebra, $Inv(B)=B\cap Inv(A)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital Banach Algebra. Let $B$ be a maximal Abelian Banach sub-algebra containing 1. I want to show that $Inv(B)=B\cap Inv(A)$, where $Inv(P)$ is the set of invertible elements in $P$.

One inclusion is trivial. For the other inclusion let $x\in B\cap Inv(A)$. We know that $b^{-1}$ exists in $A$, we need to show that it lies in $B$. I believe the idea should be to try and use $b^{-1}$ to generate an abelian sub-algebra bigger than $B$. This contradicts the maximality of $B$ and we are done.

I do not see how to generate such an sub algebra however, it seems to me that $B+b^{-1}\mathbb C$ is not a sub algebra of $A$.

Comment: Just take their generatum: the smallest subalgebra that contains $B$ and $b^{-1}$.

Comment: Let $B'$ be the sub algebra you suggested. Might it not be the case that $B'=A$. Then this does not contradict $B$ being a maximal abelian subalgebra, and it does not give that $b^{-1}$ is in $B$? Perhaps I have the wrong idea for maximal abelian sub algebra. I assume that we take maximal sup algebra to be maximal among proper subalgebras.

Comment: @Jop In this context, I would not look at non-proper subalgebras, because this is unnatural to do so. You want that a maximal abelian subalgebra of an abelian subalgebra is the entire algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b\in B$; then for any $a\in B$, $ab=ba$, so $$b^{-1}a=ab^{-1}$$
This implies that the set of polynomials generated by $B$ and $b^{-1}$ is an abelian subalgebra of $A$; each element takes the form $$\sum_{i=0}^na_ib^{-i}$$ By the above identity, the product of such elements remains in the subalgebra and commutes. Since this algebra contains $B$, but $B$ is maximal, it follows that $b^{-1}\in B$.